# Weka 3.8.1 can't link to mtj.jar, causing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: no.uib.cipr.matrix.Matrix

Tags: java, weka, mtj

I'm processing the some data in weka, and I want to use weka API so that I can use my self-defined algorithms. However, when I just want to instantiate the `LinearRegression` class: `LinearRegression myRegression = new LinearRegression()` I got the same error as: [This person got the same problem and he roll back to version 3.6.12](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42180975/3781320) I checked my `weka.jar` and I can find `mtj.jar` is included, so I'm sure there must be somewhere linked inapproriately. Downgrade the API version is not the best option for me because I want to use new class `RegressionAnalysis`. Any help thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current solution is a hack, I downloaded `mtj.jar` and added this `.jar` lib to my external lib. This hack will resolve:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: no.uib.cipr.matrix.Matrix
```

However, this hack has a flaw that it will bring up a warning:

> WARNING: Failed to load implementation from:
>   com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS

**Update:**

Same solution could apply to get rid of the warning as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "same solution"?